# Is hosting JSON files used by my iphone app on 3rd party servers a good idea?

Tags: ios, json, hosting

Here's the thing, I'm thinking of adding some "self-updating" properties to my app, which will enable the app to update it's contents every month. My current website was built using squarespace, which doesn't support file hosting. I really don't want to shell out money for another domain just for the sake of a monthly JSON file.

Are there any 3rd party providers that have this service? Such that all I need to do is upload my JSON file and get my URL? Is this a good idea?

Any help welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use a free service like [StackMob](https://www.stackmob.com/) to build your database online? This way you can update the data whenever you want. You might even build an app or a script to update the data easily and automatically.

Comment: is the database feature supported in their free model?

Comment: What do you mean by database feature? Anyway, you can replicate your data model in StackMob or similar services and create your data there. Then you just need to query their service to get it on your device as well.

Comment: Okay, well out of curiosity, does stackmob allow persistence of fixed data on the device?

Comment: StackMob only provides the server-side service. You load the data on your device and do whatever you want with it.